# Android SDK Manager - Some stuff is missing?

Tags: android, sdk, package

Im currently trying to install a few SDK packages, but some are missing.
At the moment im missing Android 3.2 API 13.

[image]

I already tried different things, setting up a proxy server, ticking Force https:// option and everytime I cleared the cache and reloaded, but nope, nothing downloads :/
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: I bet you did not try "obsoleted" option ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tick "obsolete" option

Comment: omfg. Wow. that was retarded. I did google my ass off, but I did not check that option once -.- Thanks